# Calculate work done to remove a electron at the above position from nucleus to infinity

Tags: electric-field, field-strength

i'm doing this question and I'm at the last part now. The first question wanted me to find out the electric field strength **(r= 3.0x10^-10m, q= 9.6x10^-19C)** and i used coulombs law and i managed to get the answer = **[9.6x10^10Vm^-1]**. Now the question is asking me to calculate work done to remove a electron at the above position from nucleus to infinity but I'm unsure about how to find this. I understand that *Work = QV* but the book is giving me a different answer and I'm not sure about what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks,
Neamus.

Comment: This seems like it belongs on the [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: No indication of the book you are reading. But look over [Ionization Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) for some clues, perhaps. They discuss a simple case using Hydrogen and provide good discussion on a non-quantum modeling approach, generally. They also include some qualitative discussion on approaching quantum modeling.

Answer (score 1):

Back in my school days, I have learnt this definition of potential.

*"Potential at a point in electric field is defined as the amount of work to be done on unit positive charge to bring it from infinity to that point, without accelaration."* Or you can also think like - it is the amount of work to be done on an electron to move it from that point to infinity.

So in your case, the answer is nothing but the potential at the point, where the electron is currently now. if R is the distance to electron from nuclues and E is the electric field at that point. Then: $$V = E.R$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Coulomb's Law,

$$|\vec{E}|= \frac{kq}{r^2},$$ where q = nuclear charge.
Force due to electric field on the electron is \$F_e = eE\$, where e = charge of electron.
Work done by a force is defined as : \$W = \int \vec{F}\textbf{.}\vec{dx}\$.
So work done by the electric field when electron is moved from a distance r to \$\infty\$ is:
$$W_e = \int_r ^\infty -\frac{kqe}{r^2}dr = -\frac{kqe}{r} $$
So minimum amount of work required to remove the electron (without accelerating it) is, \$W = -W_e = \frac{kqe}{r} \$